# Meaning of these Savage Garden's Affirmation lyrics

Tags: lyrics, meaning

The [lyrics](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/savagegarden/affirmation.html) of Savage Garden's *Affirmation* have this part:

> I believe the struggle for financial freedom is unfair.
>   I believe the only ones who disagree are millionaires.
>   <sub>Writers Daniel Jones and Darren Hayes</sub>

Could you help me to understand the meaning of that part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a commentary on how millionaire have financial freedom yes, but they don't care if others can achieve that same freedom. Also, how difficult and unfair it is for others- who are not millionaires- who cannot get “there” because the system is unfair and favors the rich.

They are referring to the inherent difficulties getting out of poverty in an economic system (like capitalism) wherein the game is somewhat rigged. "The American Dream" for example is nearly unattainable in today's economy as it is and portends to get worse for the poor as the new president has appointed billionaires to run things.

The lyric about 'millionaires' speaks to how the rich get richer and don't make many accommodations for the middle class or the poor.